# Update DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkbox on CellClick

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column. The cell size is larger than the checkbox so to make it user-friendly I want the CellClick event to act as if the checkbox itself was clicked.

At the moment I do this in my CellClick event:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("CONFIRM").Index Then
        If CBool(dgv.Item("CONFIRM", e.RowIndex).Value) = True Then
            dgv.Item("CONFIRM", e.RowIndex).Value = False
        Else
            dgv.Item("CONFIRM", e.RowIndex).Value = True
        End If
End If
```

However, the checkbox does not actually change state until after the cell loses focus. I've seen many suggestions about handling different events (CellValueChanged, CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged) (e.g. http://www.codingeverything.com/2013/01/firing-datagridview-cellvaluechanged.html)  and committing changes with:

```
If dgvDownloads.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        dgvDownloads.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End If
```

However this doesn't work, the dgv flickers but the checkbox doesn't change checked state.

How can I force the checkbox in a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to update it's state when the containing cell is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it more like this:

```
Public Class FormDGV

    Private Sub FormDGV_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With DataGridView1
            .Columns.Add(New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn With {
                         .Name = "Confirm",
                         .HeaderText = "Confirm"})
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
        If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
            DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        If CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Confirm").Value, Boolean) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Confirm").Value = False
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Confirm").Value = True
        End If
        Validate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, `Validate()` was the missing piece. Interestingly, if I use Validate() I don't appear to need to `.CommitEdit()` in `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`. Is this correct, if not, why do I need to do this?

Comment: I can confirm your finding where that event is not required. Seems Validate commits the value without it.

Comment: This: `CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)` is used when a DGV is un-bound or when its DataSource is a *dumb* source (a basic List(Of something). When the DGV is bound, you should/could use the `BindingSource.CurrencyManager` to update a value. But, `Me.Validate()` (or `Me.Validate(True)`, to follow the Form's `AutoValidate` setting) causes the same *effect*, here.